# How to export 3ds Max wsm to Unity?

Tags: unity, 3dsmax, export

I have made a cylinder in 3DS MAX. I then added a wave WSM. I then made the animation so it waves a bit. Then exported it to unity.

The animation works perfectly in 3ds max. When I import it to unity the animation does nothing. The cylinder looks fine.

Things I have tried. 
Game export,bake animations,embedded files.
Collapse all and collapse alone and nothing happened.
Collapsing to only deforms the cylinder, But the animation still does nothing.

Any idea how to do this?

Comment: These types of modifiers are not typically supported by game engines natively. If you show us the end result you want to create, we might be able to find a way to achieve it with vertex shaders, skeletal animation, or morph targets.

Comment: Thanks for answering the question. I was not sure if they did support it or not. I will learn the others. Thanks again.

Comment: That was not intended to be the conclusion, but a request for clarification. We can probably accomplish something equivalent, but we need more information about what you're trying to achieve before we can give you answers about how to do it.